# building hello-jni sample in Android NDK causes error "Default target help does not exist in this project"

Tags: android-ndk

Trying to build hello-jni sample in Android NDK.
Followed instructions per
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples to create build .xml,

> android update project -p . -s

Trying to run under Eclipse Helios SR2. I get this error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Default target help does not exist in
>   this project  build.xml   /HelloJni   line
>   2 Ant Buildfile Problem

in build.xml,

```
<project name="HelloJni" default="help">
```

any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your install paths of sdk and ndk are

```
~/android-sdk-mac_x86/ and ~/android-ndk-r5c
```

If you don't use Eclipse and use ant

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:~/android-ndk-r5c
cd ~/android-ndk-r5c/samples/hello-jni
ndk-build
```

Assume target 1 is the project target

```
android update project -t 1 -p ~/android-ndk-r5c/samples/hello-jni
```

or simply

```
android update project -t 1 -p .
```

Debug build

```
ant debug
```

Emulator started or device connected

```
ant install
```